# php mail() mail sent successfuly but none recieved

Tags: php, email

I'm trying to send and email using the php function `mail()`. I understood that if the function's return true it does not necessarily means the mail has been sent.

I installed the `phpmail` package and the `libphp-phpmailer` package but still nothing...

This is the code:

```
<body>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"/>
    Mail: <input type="text" name="mail"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
</form>
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(~0);

if (isset($_POST["mail"]) && isset($_POST["name"])) {
    $to_mail = $_POST["mail"];
    $to_name = ucfirst($_POST["name"]);
    $subject = "Sent using php";
    $message = "Hi " . $to_name . ", we're glad you could join us. Hope you like our page and that you're studing a lot! Good luck with whatever you're doing! :D";
    $from = "email@gmail.com";

    if(mail($to_mail, $subject, $message, $from)) {
        echo "E-Mail Sent to " . $to_mail;
    } else {
        echo "Could not send E-Mail";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: your "From" failed.

Comment: *"I installed the phpmail package and the libphp-phpmailer package but still nothing"* - That isn't phpmailer code, it's standard php `mail()`, to which I replaced the tag with.

Comment: All `mail()`'s return code is representative of is that it successfully dumped the message into the local server's queue. Whether or not anything happened after than will be in your server's logs.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Okay, I checked the `mail.log` and I did had a problem there, I solved it and now the log says the email has been sent but I still didn't actually got it int my mailbo

Comment: The "from" should be `From: email@example.com` as per the manual https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php so it may have been rejected or sent to spam then deleted.